# Django How to check if Boolean out of ModelField is True

Tags: python, django, templates, boolean, modelform

So I have this code in my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='home:login')
def profile_view(request):
    packetfree = Account.objects.get(packet_free=request.user)
    packetpremium = Account.objects.get(packet_premium=request.user)
    packetbusiness = Account.objects.get(packet_business=request.user)
    if packetfree is True:
        abo = "Free"
    elif packetpremium is True:
        abo = "Premium"
    elif packetbusiness is True:
        abo = "Business"

    context= {
        'person': request.user,
        'abo': abo

    }
    return render(request, 'home/profile.html')
```

And I want to check if the Value of the boolean from the model is true so I can find out which of the 3 booleans is true and know which subscription the user has as a Char to use it in my html template.

Comment: What if there are two `ForeignKey`s that link to the user? The modeling does not look very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise to *remodel* this and use a field with `choices`, or a `ForeignKey` to an `AccountType` model if new types of accounts can be created. Right now three `ForeignKey`s are used, and these all have to work with a *different* `related_name`, this makes code inelegant and queries more complicated, here for example you make three queries to the database.

We can remodel this for a fixed number of account types as:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Account(models.Model):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = [
        (0, 'free')
      , (1, 'premium')
      , (2, 'business')
      ]
    account_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

In that case you can fetch the type of the account with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required(login_url='home:login')
def profile_view(request):
    packet = get_object_or_404(Account, user=request.user)
    abo = packet.get_account_type_display()
    
    context= {
        'person': request.user,
        'abo': abo
    }
    return render(request, 'home/profile.html', context)
```

If you want to work with an arbitrary number of `Account` types, you can model this as:

```
class AccountType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Account(models.Model):
    account_type = models.ForeignKey(
        AccountType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Comment: this seems to be very elegant, thank you. How can I set the account_type I tried it with account_type=0 because it's an integer field but then this error appears: 

OperationalError
no such column: StartSite_account.account_type

Comment: @FLYAX: you first will need to migrate the database.

Comment: yeah, I already noticed, oopsie, but now I have another problem, I did it as you said but the value isnt showing up

Comment: @FLYAX: what does `print(packet.account_type)` prints?

Comment: "0", and that correct in the db is also the value 0. So the error must be in the template


    `<p class="black">Abo: {{ abo }}</p>`

Comment: @FLYAX: what does `print(packet.get_account_type_display())` prints? Are you sure your field is named `account_type`?

Comment: nope other idea the `get_account_type_display()` thing is this a default method or do I have to create it first, otherwise I tried `abo = packet.account_type` but it still doesnt show up

Comment: print(packet.get_account_type_display()) doesnt print something

Comment: @FLYAX: no for each field named `fieldname` with `choices`, it makes a `get_fieldname_display`. Are you sure you are triggering the correct view, and rendering the right template? What if you restart the server?

Comment: yeah i rendered it correctly but it hast to be something with the display method because I cant print it

Comment: @FLYAX: you did use `choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE` in the `IntegerField` right?

Comment: yeah this is my models.py https://hastebin.com/ewosajugox.py

Comment: @FLYAX: can you share the (updated) view as well?

Comment: @FLYAX: locally I can not reproduce the problem, especially since if this method does not exists, it would raise an error. well it should at least print something, what does it print with `print(('A', packet.get_account_type_display()))`?

Comment: the A wasnt printed, thats weird because the print(packet.account_type) worked

Comment: @FLYAX: I think there is something that prevents the view from being triggered, or perhaps Django uses the precompiled `*.pyc` files, and thus is working with an "old" version of your view.

Comment: so what should I check/do to fix my problem?

Comment: @FLYAX: remove the `__pycache__` directories and `*.pyc` files (not `.py`, the `.pyc` contain bytecode), stop the Django server, and restart the server.

Comment: still doesnt work

here are all my important files, did I render something wrong https://hastebin.com/ikevuqupig.kotlin

Comment: @FLYAX: what URL do you visit? Can you share the "root `urls.py`" as well?

Comment: @FLYAX: these do not mention the urls of your home app?

Comment: they do, the StartSite.urls include the home urls

Comment: @FLYAX: can you then share the `StartSite.urls`?

Comment: its still inside the link --> https://hastebin.com/ikevuqupig.kotlin

Comment: ok, update I had 2 consoles opened and the console print thing works, just the template doesnt work, any ideas what could be wrong

Comment: i did it, the context wasnt in the render

Comment: @FLYAX: aaarrrggghhh, yes... So that means it works now?